# OpenFileDialog alternative component in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp, openfiledialog

Is there another component for FileBrowsing instead of OpenFileDialog in C#? 
The OpenFileDialog, downloads ftp file to local temp, but i want the ftp path of file.

Is There alternative component for OpenFileDialog in C#?

Comment: You are asking for the wrong solution.  This stoopid non-feature is just as painful when the user uses another program to browse the ftp server folder, like Explorer or Notepad.  So fix the real problem, disable the feature.  You'll have to ask at superuser.com, be sure to mention the OS since it looks like this is strongly linked to a Win7 add-in or bug.

Comment: Roll your own, buy a 3rd party product or work out another way altogether like DropBox or ftp client component, closing as a exact duplicate